# Changing woocommerce product subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I was gonna change the woocommerce subtotal but it only applies to cart page but not globally such as checkout, emails, etc.. Below are the codes I added on functions.php, can someone help me sort it out. Thank you

```
function woocommerce_cart_subtotal(  $cart_subtotal ){
    global $pur_mode, $line_subtotal;
    $line_subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $listt = $cart_item['list-cart-type'];      
        $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $listt == $pur_mode && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $line_subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];                 
        }
    }   
    $cart_subtotal = $line_subtotal;
    return $cart_subtotal;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 99, 3 );
```

I was expecting that the value on cart page will also be the same value as on checkout page, as in globally the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just figured out that global variable were not passing to checkout page..

Below codes saves my day:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
function wc_session_enabler() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
}

// Changing Cart Sub total
function woocommerce_cart_subtotal(  $cart_subtotal ){
    global $pur_mode, $line_subtotal;
    $line_subtotal = 0;
    $pur_mode = WC()->session->get('pur_mode');
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $listt = $cart_item['list-cart-type'];      
        $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $listt == $pur_mode && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $line_subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];                 
        }
    }   
    $cart_subtotal = $line_subtotal;
    return $cart_subtotal;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 99, 3 );
```